What is the hypnotized person thinking while under the control of Loki's scepter?
During the MCU we see that the scepter has the ability to mind control people turning their eyes bright blue and making them do whatever the person wielding it says.
What exactly is the mind controlled person thinking while under the influence of the scepter?
Do they think that the person using it is the best person in the world and will follow whatever they say or is it more like "oh shit I hate this person but I guess I have no choice in what I can do".
Do they recognize the actions they are doing are evil?

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This would be a lot easier to read if you broke it into paragraphs.

It's impossible to know as it is not shown/revealed. My theory is that given that the scepter was what gave Wanda her powers (or at least related), I believe what they might be seeing something similar to what is happening in Avengers: Age of Ultron, when Wanda messes with the Avengers' minds - just random visions of things.

I've taken the liberty of editing this into shape. It's a pretty decent question if you remove the chatter.

During the scene in Avengers where Barton is recovering from Loki's mind control, he describes the experience to Natasha as such: "Have you ever had someone take your brain and play?  Pull you out?  Stuff something else in?  You know what it's like to be unmade?"  It seems to imply that their mind is shoved aside or suppressed and "something else" is in the driver's seat.

"Hey, this Loki guy has some good points. He's just asking questions."

I think better citation from the script for Avengers is:

            NATASHA
      Clint, you're gonna be alright.

                     CLINT BARTON
      You know that? Is that what you know? I
      got...I gotta go in though. I gotta
      flush him out.

                     NATASHA
      We don't have that long, it's gonna
      take time.

          CLINT BARTON
      I don't understand. Have you ever had
      someone take your brain and play? Pull
      you out and send something else in? Do
      you know what it's like to be unmade?

                     NATASHA
     You know that I do.

                      CLINT BARTON
     Why am I back? How did you get him out?

                     NATASHA
     Cognitive recalibration. I hit you
     really hard in the head.


Natasha mentions her brainwashing by the Red Room and I think it's a fine comparison. The controlled guys are different, brainwashed, versions of themselves. They still have free will, but want to help Loki, do what he wants. Barton thinks as if Loki was in his head, but it was perhaps rather an overlay, temporary modification warping his mind, which was holding till he got "recalibrated".

Interesting very well put. So if I was put under it I'd be normal basically but I'd just want to help the other person?

You'd be a different version of yourself, it does more than change loyalty.

If we take the script for Avengers as a guide, we get a pretty good view of what a hypnotised person is thinking, e.g. Not very much of anything. Selvig seems to act like he's drunk or drugged or, well, hypnotised.

TONY: Shut it down, Dr. Selvig.
SELVIG: It's too late! It can't stop now. He wants to show us something! A new universe.

Selvig is described as having "woken up" after Loki stops controlling him.

[SELVIG WAKES UP FROM LOKI MIND CONTROL. He looks around, confused where he is. He looks up at the sky, amazed.]

And after some initial confusion, he begins to remember what he's been up to for the last couple of days, and there's even a suggestion that he may have had some limited control over his actions, although more of a subconscious resistance rather than anything the level of executive function.

SELVIG: Loki's scepter, the energy...the Tesseract can't fight. You can't protect against yourself.
BLACK WIDOW: It's not your fault. You didn't know what you were doing.
SELVIG: Well, actually I think I did. I built in a safety to cut the power source.


It reminds me of an episode of Avengers: Earth's Mightiest Heroes in which Purple Man took control of the entire Earth through Tony Stark, but the latter still tried to resist his control (although he was still conscious; he just couldn't fully exert his free will, but he did manage to subconsciously do some things).

Hey sorry for the late reply I appreciate you editing the post it was very convuluted I have to admit so thanks for not being a jerk about it since I am new here. I have another question however. Can someone not linked to the mind stone use it? For example if I used the scepter on you to steal me a car would it work?
